# Using sed to get specific text from XML file

Tags: sed, regular-expression, xml

Not sure why I'm not getting this. I've been searching and testing my command for a couple hours and I'm not getting anywhere.

The text is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><result expand="changes,testResults,metadata,logEntries,plan,vcsRevisions,artifacts,comments,labels,jiraIssues" key="EP-ED-JOB1-174" state="Failed" lifeCycleState="Finished" number="174" ....
```

And I just want to pull out the  `state="Failed"`  part, it could also be `state="Successful"`.

I've tried a million variations of this:

```
sed '/state=".*"/p' htmlResponse.txt
```

But paren's, escape slashes etc seem to match the entire chunk of text. What's wrong with my regex?

Comment: you need to use capture groups around what you want and use substitution to print only those portion.. to avoid greedy issue, in this case you can use `[^"]*` instead of `.*`... but really, you should use xml parser instead of regex

Comment: If I do `sed -n '/state="[^"]*/p' htmlResponse.html` it still gives me back everything.

Comment: Use `xmllint` instead. Use the right tools for the right job.

Comment: Your XML document is not well formed. Please show a complete, or at least parseable, representation of the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Putting aside the obligatory "you should really be using a proper XML parser because regexes aren't powerful enough to parse XML" comment, I see two problems in your `sed` line:

1. `".*"` will match from the first `"` to the last, since `.` matches `"`
2. The `sed` command `/.../p` prints the *whole line* if it matches the regex.

Here's two things I'd suggest for quick-and-dirty HTML-scraping shell scripts:

1. Use `"[^"]*"` to match "quote, any number of non-quote characters, end quote"
2. It's lots easier to use `grep -o` to pull out bits of a file that match a regex

So that would make your command more like:

```
grep -o 'state="[^"]*"'
```

Or, if you really *must* use sed:

```
sed -n 's/.*\(state="[^"]*"\).*/\1/p'
```

Comment: Thanks! I went with grep as the command just looks easier to type and understand.

Answer (score 3):

The right way is to use XML parsers like **xmlstarlet**:

```
printf 'state="%s"\n' $(xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//result/@state" -n htmlResponse.txt)
```

The output:

```
state="Failed"
```

To only get the value of the attribute (from all `result` nodes, if there are several):

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//result/@state" -n htmlResponse.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You likely want to match the whole line and print [just the matching group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17511639/sed-print-only-matching-group):

```
sed -r 's/.*state="([^"]*)".*/\1/' htmlResponse.txt
```

That actually just pulls out the `Failed` or `Successful` (without including the `state=` part that precedes it),  which I suspect is what you want. But if you do need that, you can add it back easily, or use a slightly different regex, [as in wwoods's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/398442/11938).

However, as [Sundeep mentions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/398439/using-sed-to-get-specific-text-from-file#comment711447_398439), it is [not at all robust to parse HTML (or XML) with a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). It's one thing to use `grep` or `sed` to search for things interactively, but if this is part of a script that needs to carry out an important task *and actually work*, you should parse the XML properly.